# Pivot in Presto SQL if you don't know the column names in advance

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a set of records showing the status of implementation of software  scomponents. Each row has a feature area, a feature within that area, the product where that feature appears, and its implementation status (green, red, or yellow), like this:

| Feature_Area | Feature | Product | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User experience | Sign Up | App1 | Green |
| User experience | Sign Up | App2 | Red |
| User experience | Log off | App1 | Green |
| User experience | Log off | App2 | Red |
| Back End | Update User | App3 | Green |
| Back End | Delete User | App3 | Red |

I'd like to pivot this as shown here:
[image]

Specifically, I'd like a single row for each feature area and columns for each app to show the status of that feature.

I tried grouping by Feature_Area and then creating columns like this:

COALESCE(
ARBITRARY(IF
product = 'App1',
status,
'N/A'
)) AS "App1"

But for my use cases, the app name will change with the data (e.g., I could have App5, App6, etc.) so I can't list the column names in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the columns. Presto/Trino does not support dynamic pivoting, at least at the moment (also what if you have a lot of different values in `Product` column). One thing you can do is to use "outside" scripting - read the data and dynamically generate the query.